# django rest framework simulate required_permissions

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

often when i define permissions on my django views I would use something like this

```
@permission_required('comment.add_thread',  raise_exception=True)
def save_comment(request, id=None):
  """ """
```

But, when rest framework, how can I tell the API method to check for comment.add_thread permission before performing the operation?

Answer (score 1):

It all depends how you create your api views, if your view is not generic, then you need to create your own permission like this:

```
from rest_framework import permissions

class AddCommentPermission(permissions.BasePermission):

    def has_permission(self, request, view):
        return request.user.has_perm('comment.add_thread')
```

but if your view has a model property set, then you just simply use `DjangoModelPermissions`, as documented here:

http://django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/permissions.html#djangomodelpermissions